# challenging digit sum problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an interesting problem having to do with digit sum! but the problem is challenging for a novice like me.  I have copied the interesting problem in the lines under.

> Consider a number $N$ which is created by concatenating the numbers $1$ through $\underbrace{99\ldots99}_{k\ 9\text{'s}}$ inclusive. For example, if $k=2$, then $N=1234567891011\dots9899$. Find a formula for the digit sum of $N$ in terms of $k\ge1$.

this is very sophisticated problem for a novice like me but i like the challenge! i will be detailing the strategy i am thinking of in the following lines!

so it is going from $1$ to $99...999$ so the number of 1 and 9 will be the same! same with any pair that can be taken! so hear me out here.... we can count the number of 1's in N! now i will call this x! the answer will be $(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)x=45x$
now the problem is to find x! this is a complicated issue that i cannot seem to get anywhere with! i am asking for everyone's help on this problem! please enter in your thoughts on how to continue.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In my view, all these exclamation points simply make your question harder to read.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that your post has $51$ exclamation marks?

Comment: Count the number of $0$s in the concatenated number and subtract them off.  You have shown that each digit is exactly $\frac 19$ of the remaining digits, which tells you $x$.

Comment: Can! You! Please! Stop! Shouting!

Comment: i like to add ! to show my excitement when doing math problems !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

consider $k=2$
the sum of the digits will be unchanged if we include leading zeros.
i.e. we are using
$$N=00010203...979899$$
there are 200 digits in all, $20$ copies of each digit from $0$ to $9$.
so $$S_2 = 20(45)=900$$
for $k=3$ we have $3000$ digits, $300$ copies of each one
so $$S_3 = 300(45)= 13500$$
This suggests that the general formula is
$$S_k = 45k\cdot 10^{k-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

In the numbers $0\ldots (10^k-1)$, each digit appears in the ones place in one-tenth of those numbers: $\frac{1}{10}\cdot10^{k}=10^{k-1}$. So just adding the digits that originally come from the ones place, you have $(0+1+2+\cdots+9) 10^{k-1}=45\cdot 10^{k-1}$.

Nothing changes as you consider the tens place. In the numbers $1\ldots (10^k-1)$, each digit appears in the tens place one-tenth of the time. So just adding the digits that originally come from the tens place, you have $(0+1+2+\cdots+9) 10^{k-1}=45\cdot 10^{k-1}$.

Continuing in this way, summing digits from the $10^0$ place, the $10^1$ place, up to the $10^{k-1}$ place, the total sum would be $k$ copies of the same number: $$k\cdot45\cdot10^{k-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the numbers $0-9$ is $45$. So if $k=1$, the digit sum is $45$.

Now say $k=2$. The numbers $0-9$ will cycle ten times as ones digits. So that sum is $450$. As tens digits, the tens digit $0$ will be repeated ten times (although this will not show in the actual number) then $1$ is repeated ten times, and so on until the numbers $0-9$ are repeated ten times each, the same as the ones digits. Total: $900$.

We notice a pattern: The ones digits will cycle as many times as $10^{k-1}$. The tens digit will do the same, in a different order. This pattern continues. But each time, the sum is $45$.

So the sum will be $45k\cdot{10^{k-1}}$.